# Tag editing request: [tag:flashflashrevolution] -> [tag:flash-flash-revolution]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The name of the game contains spaces (see the copyright thingy on there bottom of [here](http://www.flashflashrevolution.com/)), therefore there should be hyphens in the tag to make it more readable.

[flashflashrevolution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flashflashrevolution) -> [flash-flash-revolution](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash-flash-revolution)

Comment: Thanks to StrixVaria, the [one question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125520/in-flash-flash-revolution-how-do-i-unlock-the-secret-song-final-fantasy-last-b) affected is changed